# Can function names be multiple characters long?

Tags: functions, notation

In Python (and every other programming language) you can have a function with more characters long name. For example, `print('x')`.

I have wondered, if this is possible in math, too. I have found that you can have a function with Latin name (somewhere I have found that group homomorphism can be marked with big phi, so even Greek letters are included). You can also add bars at the names ($f´(x)$). You can add indexes ($f_1(x)$). (Small question: Can be functions named in Hebrew alphabet?)

**Main question:** Can be functions named with more characters (for example, $ab(x)$)?

Comment: I suppose that $\operatorname{ker}$ is an example of such a function/operator

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch And $im$ then. But can I name function in general case, not by convention?

Comment: Well, the nice thing about mathematics is that it is "free", so you can name your functions however you please (you just have to state it)

Comment: @Maximialian Janisch Isn't then confused $ker(x)$ with $k*e*r(x)$?

Comment: This is why I used \operatorname . I want to comment that the readers of math texts are much less pedantic than computers (don't get me wrong - I like coding a lot), so they will be able to tell based on context whether you mean $k\cdot e\cdot r(x)$ or $\operatorname{ker}(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation for trigonometric functions uses multiple letters, with especially many if they are inverse, get a c at the end (e.g. $\operatorname{tanc}x$), [hyperbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions) or non-standard, e.g. the [haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versine#Haversine). (The idea of a function named $\operatorname{archaversinch}x$ is amusing.)

Other examples include $\exp$, $\ln$ and $\operatorname{erf}$. Then you get special functions such as [Airy functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function#Definitions), [Clausen functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#General_definition), the [cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral), [exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Definitions) and [sine integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral), [Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Definition), and so on. Pretty much every function named [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_abbreviations) is suitable.

Note, however, that multiple-letter names are typically deitalicised, e.g. `\exp` is equivalent to `\operatorname{exp}`.

Comment: You made my day with archaversinch $x$.